# Among the 2, 598, 960 all the 5 hand poker cards how many contain at least one black card

Tags: combinatorics

Of all the 5 hand poker cards how many contain at least one black card?

How would I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: How many hands can you make without any black cards? Subtract this from the total.

> $\displaystyle\binom{52}{5}-\binom{26}{5}=2533180$

Comment: Well theres only 26 red cards so 5 right?

Comment: Try again. Where did you get 2,598,960?

Comment: It was in the question

Comment: 1299480 should I just divide it by 2?

Comment: oh yes 65780 .. so 2,598,960 - 65780 = 2533180

Comment: 2533180 is correct